# перекрестные указатели в классах

Tags: c++

перекрестные указатели в классах - наверно в эту сторону.

Есть класс "A", он содержит поле имеющее тип - указатель на класс "B".
И в "B" так же должен быть указатель на объект "A" . Сначала создаётся объект A
с пустым полем b. Потом создаётся объект B и при помощи setB указывается указатель на объект A.
Оба класса имеют метод print() их тела смотреть ниже.
Всё просто казалось бы, но у меня не собирается.

кстати, может фантастика, но возможно ли сделать данную задачу 3мя файлами main.cpp и A.h, B.h ,
причем все определения методов разместить внутри классов A и B ?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"


int main() {
    A a;
    B b(&a);
    a.setB(&b);
    a.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    b.print();
}
```

A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"


class A {
    B* b ;
public:
    A();
    void setB(B* b_);
    void print();
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
class B {
    A* a;
public:

    B(A* a_);
    void print();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
A::A():b(nullptr) {}
void A::setB(B* b_) { b = b_; }
void A::print() { std::cout << "print from A" << std::endl;b->print(); }
```

B.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

B::B(A* a_): a(a_) {}
void B::print(){ std::cout << "print from B" << std::endl;a->print(); }
```

Comment: В `A.h` вместо `#include "B.h"` написать `class B;`, то же и в `B.h`, только `class A;`. И почитать о предварительных объявлениях классов

Comment: Это когда "class A" пишем без определения ? У меня не удалось тоже с ним

Comment: https://fex.net/ru/s/8m5bkym Если все сделать правильно, то все компилируется. И работает. Как вами и написано - с бесконечной рекурсией :)

Comment: почему с бесконечной рекурсией ? там же прагмы стоят

Comment: Прагмы — это для компиляции....  А я говорю о выполнении программы. В которой `a->print()` вызывает `b->print()`, которая вызывает `a->print()`, которая...

Comment: @Harry , мне наверно ваш fex.net забанен. ссылка не открывается :( . вы там наверно исходник накидали ? Бесконечные рекурсии - согласен, прошляпил.  по первому вашему сообщению попробовал сделать. не вышло. не собирается :(

Comment: Ну возьмите vpn какой... Или напишите адрес, куда вам выслать.

Comment: @Harry , спасибо,  если можно тогда сюда andron81_81@mail.ru